# VHDL LFSR Output through FPGA board SMA connector

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I recently started working on an FPGA project for school, I have never worked with VHDL before so I tried my best to piece my program together. Overall, my goal is to make a prbs or LFSR to generate randomly. My vhdl code checks out in xilinx ISE software and runs in testbench fine but I need to flash the project to the board and connect an oscilloscope to one of the SMA connectors on the board, My question is how can I i forward my outputs to a single SMA connector on the Spartan 6 board

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity LFSR is
port (
  clock    : std_logic;
  reset    : std_logic;
  data_out : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
 );
 end LFSR;

 architecture Behavioral of LFSR is

 signal lfsr_reg : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);

begin

 process (clock)
variable lfsr_tap : std_logic;
begin
if clock'EVENT and clock='1' then
  if reset = '1' then
    lfsr_reg <= (others => '1');
  else
    lfsr_tap := lfsr_reg(6) xor lfsr_reg(9);
    lfsr_reg <= lfsr_reg(8 downto 0) & lfsr_tap;
  end if;
end if;
 end process;

  data_out <= lfsr_reg;

end Behavioral;
```

Now I just want to forward the output/outputs to an SMA connector so I can get the results on the oscilloscope, any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to map your I/Os to actual pins on your FPGA chip. This is done in a constraints file (typically a `.ucf`), which you can either hand-edit (it's just text), or let a tool handle for you.

In the newer ISE tools PlanAhead is responsible for this - you can open it from the ISE Processes Pane (select User Constraints -> I/O Pin Planning (PlanAhead) - Post-synthesis).

This opens PlanAhead and gives you a list of the I/Os in your design (your `clock`, `reset` and `data_out`). Now you just need to map these to the correct FPGA pins. Have a look in your board documentation to find the locations of your clock-input, push-buttons (for reset) and SMA connector.

PlanAhead should create the `.ucf` file for you, and add it to your project. Afterwards you can edit it in the ISE editor - it's pretty self-explanatory once you have some initial content in it.

Also, check out [this Xilinx guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_4/ise_tutorial_ug695.pdf) (from page 100 and onwards) for a step-by-step guide.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try this. I used the plan ahead program and used dataout 6 for example and set the output to B3 which on the Spartan 6 board is one of the SMA connectors but nothing happened. The program made NET "data_out[6]" LOC = B3; that line into the .ucf file. Just trying to get the generated random bit to appear on an oscilloscope from the fpga board. Is there anything else I am not doing, or is it just the ucf file thats causing the problem for me ?

Comment: Have you connected a clock signal also?

Comment: Yes. I was able to get something to show up on the oscilloscope. I have one of the bits appearing using the suggested method with the ucf. So i have one of the data_outs appearing to fluctuate between 1 and 0. What I really need is to show the combined bits to appear on the oscilloscope, when I run the test bench I have a data_out[9,0] that gives me my random number generated between 0-1023... i want to have that random number appear on the oscilloscope...any ideas?

Comment: You will either need one output pin (and thus also one channel on your scope) for each bit, or you will have to serialize your signal - that is, output one bit after another on your output signal. There are ip-cores for this, but writing one yourself for this case shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Your SMA connector can only hold a single output, not a bus.
To see the MSB of your LFSR just add the following lines to your .ucf file:

```
NET clock        LOC = $PIN; 
NET reset        LOC = $PIN; 
NET dataout<9>   LOC = $PIN; # your SMA output
NET dataout<8>   LOC = $PIN;
NET dataout<7>   LOC = $PIN;
NET dataout<6>   LOC = $PIN;
NET dataout<5>   LOC = $PIN;
NET dataout<4>   LOC = $PIN;
NET dataout<3>   LOC = $PIN;
NET dataout<2>   LOC = $PIN;
NET dataout<1>   LOC = $PIN;
NET dataout<0>   LOC = $PIN;
```

See in your board documentation (or schematic) for the right pins and add the right pin names in your .ucf file. 
I suggest to use some LEDs for the remaining outputs of dataout.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try this. I used the plan ahead program and used dataout 6 for example and set the output to B3 which on the Spartan 6 board is one of the SMA connectors but nothing happened. The program made  NET "data_out[6]" LOC = B3; that line into the .ucf file.

Comment: Just trying to get the generated random bit to appear on an oscilloscope from the fpga board. Is there anything else I am not doing, or is it just the ucf file thats causing the problem for me  ?

Comment: The tools generate also a pinout report. Is there everything allright?

Comment: Is the clock pin connection right? Did you see the clock on your scope? How is the polarity of your reset input?